# Write a program that first reads in the name of an input file, followed by two strings representing the lower and upper bounds of a search range

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, strip, readlines

I want to write a program that first reads in an input file, followed by two strings representing the lower and upper bounds of a search range. The file should be read using the file.readlines() method. The input file contains a list of alphabetical, ten-letter strings, each on a separate line. Your program should output all strings from the list that are within that range (inclusive of the bounds).

And the contents of input1.txt are:

```
aspiration
classified
federation
graduation
millennium
philosophy
quadratics
transcript
wilderness
zoologists
```

If the input is:

```
ammoniated
millennium
```

Here is my code:

```
f=open('input1.txt')
str1=input()
str2=input()

word_in_file= f.readlines()

for word in word_in_file:
    word=word.strip()
    if str1<=word<=str2:
        print(word)
f.close()
```

the output is:

```
aspiration
classified
federation
graduation
millennium
```

When I tried for another attempt, which I only removes the line `word=word.strip()`, my output turned into:

```
aspiration

classified

federation

graduation
```

My question is why the last string `millennium` is no longer included in the output?

Comment: I suspect that ‘millennium’ with crlf on the end is considered greater than the search limit. As an experiment try: ‘milleniun’ as the end term.

Answer (score 0):

When you read lines from file like this they ends with `\r\n` and `'millennium\r\n'` is greater than `'millennium'`. You can use slicing to get rid of it. For example:

```
line = line[:-2]
```

or replace them with empty string

```
line = line.replace('\r\n', '')
```

Comment: How do you know that they end in `\r\n` and not with `\n`?

Comment: If they may end with `\n`, one could simply do `line = line.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')`.

Answer (score 0):

The empty lines between the second output should give a hint.  Without the `strip()` call, you're comparing strings with newlines to strings without them, meaning you're doing a comparison like this:

```
# str1 <= word <= str2
"ammoniated" <= "millennium\n" <= "millennium"
```

(Your string might end in `\r\n` instead of `\n`, depending on your platform)

According to string comparison rules, this will be false, since the string `"millennium\n"`, with the newline, occurs lexicographically after `"millennium"`, without it.